# window.open redirects to a URL but the original window shows a white blank page after redirection

Tags: java, servlets, redirect

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
out.print("<script>");
out.print("window.open('http://chfdsd/manu/zseriessection9.pdf','_blank')");
out.print("</script>");
```

This snippet is in a action class in struts. I am using it to redirect to the URL in a new window. But, the parent window should not change after this script is executed. But that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're performing a direct request to the server. The server response is just that piece of hardcoded JavaScript which will be written in your browser client. If you check the source code of your *blank page* you will see that code:

```xml
<script>
    window.open('http://chfdsd/manu/zseriessection9.pdf','_blank')
</script>
```

So it's not showing a *blank page*, just a response with no HTML component to display.

To solve your problem, you have some options:

- Perform this request in a new page/tab, then the servlet request return a redirect to the desired page/content. For example:

  ```html
  <form action="${request.contextPath}/path/to/Servlet" target="blank">
      <!-- your form components... -->
  </form>
  ```

  And in your Servlet:

  ```
  response.redirect("http://chfdsd/manu/zseriessection9.pdf");
  //no need to use PrintWriter at all
  ```
- Perform an ajax request that returns the URL to navigate. Then, process the ajax response to navigate to this URL in a new page. Using jquery:

  ```
  $.post("${request.contextPath}/path/to/Servlet", function(response) {
      window.open(response, 'blank');
  });
  ```

  Then in your servlet:

  ```
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
  out.print("http://chfdsd/manu/zseriessection9.pdf");
  ```

Note that there are more elegant solutions, but any of these will do.